# Why Prestashop's checkout template doesn't extend page.tpl?

Tags: templates, themes, overriding, prestashop, checkout

In prestashop 1.7, the checkout template file `themes/classic/templates/checkout/checkout.tpl` uses its own html structure instead of extending `page.tpl`, like every other checkout pages (cart, order confirmation, etc).

Why is that? Is there any security flaw we should be aware of?

I've overriden `checkout.tpl` in my own theme `{extends file='page.tpl'}` and I want to make sure that everything's alright:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='content'}
  <section id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        {block name='cart_summary'}
          {render file='checkout/checkout-process.tpl' ui=$checkout_process}
        {/block}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">

        {block name='cart_summary'}
          {include file='checkout/_partials/cart-summary.tpl' cart = $cart}
        {/block}

        {hook h='displayReassurance'}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{/block}
```

Thanks!

Florian

Comment: I think there are no security reasons but only design reason. Mostly checkout pages are remarkably different from the main page so much easier to have different layouts. But, also, it's only my opinion

Comment: I think it's intended to make the checkout page focused on only one objective. No menues or banners etc and no distractions